# How to split an array elements exactly into two and store it in two separate variable

Tags: php, arrays

I want to split a `PHP` array like `excel{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"...}` and store the elements in two separate array like `excel1{"a", "b", "c", "d"}` and `excel2{"e", "f", "g"}`
how do I do that? please someone help me to solve this. cause I am new to `PHP`

Comment: refer this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php. Its very simple, did you search any solution in web?

Comment: Please mention the criteria for breaking the array.

Comment: main array is a dynamic array and want to split it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) :

```
$half_length = ceil(count($excel)/2);
$excel1 = array_slice($excel, 0, $half_length);
$excel2 = array_slice($excel, $half_length);
```

Comment: if you have 11 arrays then it would result to 5.5 you should floor it like my answer.

Comment: yes, @Viscocent; I think the question was juste an example, not to get the half.

Comment: it would store first half in the first array and remaining elements in the second array

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$your_array = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
$half = floor($your_array/2);
$array1 = array_slice($your_array, 0,$half);
$array2 = array_slice($your_array, $half);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$tab_excel = explode(",", $excel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how to Split an array into chunks - PHP

```
 <?php
 $input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
 print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
 print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
 ?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php